# Where to find generic weight take off charts for planes?

Tags: takeoff, runways, aeronautical-charts

Where can I find a generic weight take off chart for planes? I looked online but maybe I'm not looking in the right place?
Related: [How do I use the takeoff and landing distance charts in the C172 POH?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/how-do-i-use-the-takeoff-and-landing-distance-charts-in-the-c172-poh)

Comment: Who would have produced "generic" performance charts? Are you talking about mass production aircraft? Also, the takeoff performance would be different for different weights, engines, design. I  will be anxious to see if there is such a thing.

Comment: @757toga Maybe a chart generator with inputs for airfoil and weight along with other specs.

Comment: Perhaps,  but who would pay for something like that and what use would it be?

Comment: By generic do you want something that just looks the part? How do you intend to use one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a thing does not exist. There is nothing like a "generic" aircraft, the sheer number of variables and breadth of their values makes any attempt to produce such a thing highly implausible.

Useful takeoff performance data is only available for fully engineered and prototyped aircraft. The prototype can be computationally simulated but that is not some web app, it is a team of researchers with access to specialized facilities. (Something like a flight simulator is not an engineering tool. Flight simulators just copy existing aircraft data, they do not do any fluid dynamics or similar computation.)